# `git gc` without packing objects?

Tags: git

I'd like to remove objects (`.git/objects`) from my repository that are no longer referenced by any refs, but **I don't want to pack to pack files**.

I tried `git gc --no-prune` but it still removed all objects from my repo and left only packfiles (`git count-objects` reports "0 objects, 0 kilobytes").

Comment: How does what you want differ from what `git prune` does?

Comment: Oops, I was not aware of `prune`, thank you. Want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git gc` is a wrapper for a whole series of smaller maintenance operations:

- `git reflog expire`
- `git repack`
- `git prune-packed` (actually done by `git repack` automatically when you use `-d`)
- `git prune`
- any others I may have forgotten

and `git prune` is the one that specifically removes unreferenced objects.  Note that `git gc` supplies an expiry time so that `git prune` won't remove unreferenced objects that are still being constructed.  If you have no active Git commands that might be constructing objects, and don't want to provide the gc default grace period, you don't need to worry about this.